# What is belongs_to creates in rails migrations and in the database structure?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, rails-migrations

I'm confused about belongs_to and foreign key in rails. When we use belongs_to in rails migrations, it seems like it creates a foreign key on the child table that we can access from the parent table. However, in the rails documentation, there is a situation that uses both in one column.

```
create_table :accounts do |t|
  t.belongs_to :supplier, index: { unique: true }, foreign_key: true
  # ...
end
```

Can somebody explain this situation and explain the what belongs_to and foreign_key: true exactly does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`t.belongs_to :supplier` adds `supplier_id` to `accounts`.

`index: { unique: true }` creates a [database index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index) for the column.

`foreign_key: true` creates a [foreign key constraint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) for the column.

I recommend you to read [Active Record Migrations — Ruby on Rails Guides](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html).

Indexes speed up data retrieval operations.

Foreign keys help to maintain [referential integrity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_integrity).

Comment: so t.belongs_to :supplier equals to t.integer :supplier_id?